# Pivot inside a ScrollViewer, scrollviewer wont scroll

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, scrollviewer

I have a page that has many UI elements and its scrollable vertical like a Timeline. In the middle I have a pivot that when its gets focus or the mouse pointer enters the scrollviewer stop scrolling.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="180"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="360*" MaxWidth="1060"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <!-- more UI elements-->
    <Pivot ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" x:Name="InfoPivot" Title="Pivot" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxWidth="1060" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinHeight="500">
        <PivotItem Header="Mylist">
            <GridView x:Name="theList" Margin="20,10,10,13" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GridViewTemplate1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution but I hope there is a better way.

**Edit**: Changed the division it makes it feel more like the the default scroll.

```
private void PivotItem_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.GetCurrentPoint(scrollViewer).Properties.MouseWheelDelta == (-120))
    {
        // On Mouse Wheel scroll Backward
        scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, scrollViewer.VerticalOffset + Window.Current.CoreWindow.Bounds.Height / 7, null, false);
    }
    if (e.GetCurrentPoint(scrollViewer).Properties.MouseWheelDelta == (120))
    {
        // On Mouse Wheel scroll Forward
        scrollViewer.ChangeView(null,scrollViewer.VerticalOffset - Window.Current.CoreWindow.Bounds.Height / 7, null, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work but doesn't seem to coast or have acceleration. did you ever find a better way to fix this?

Comment: @BobBurningham Nope haven't invested any time after I fixed it, it went to the bottom of my priorities.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/scroll-controls) prescribes that we don't put a [Pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pivot) inside a [ScrollViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer).

> Don't place a Pivot control inside a scroll viewer to avoid conflicts with pivot's scrolling logic.

The [PointerWheelChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_PointerWheelChanged) doc says:

> Specific Windows Runtime controls may have class-based handling for the PointerWheelChanged input event. If so, the control probably has an override for the method OnPointerWheelChanged. Typically the event is marked handled by the class handler, and the PointerWheelChanged event is not raised for handling by any user code handlers on that control. A control might do this in order to support traversal of its child elements by using a pointer wheel action.

A note on the [GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview) and [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview) docs also applies to `Pivot`.

> The PointerWheelChanged event does not bubble up from a GridView. This means that a control that has a GridView inside of it does not receive mouse wheel change messages if the pointer is over the GridView. For example, if you put a GridView inside of a ScrollViewer, you can't scroll the ScrollViewer with the mouse wheel when the pointer is over the GridView.