# UWP Disable mouse scroll in grid view

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I have a hub that is set to a vertical orientation that contains multiple HubSections. In each of these HubSections is a horiztonally scrolling grid view. For an example of a similar layout, take a look at the home screen of the Windows store.

I want to prevent the mouse scroll from moving the list horizontally and, instead, to continue scrolling vertically. I have images in place, similar to the Windows Store, to allow the user to manually slide the grid view. I also want to enable swiping to move the list, similar to what the store does.

I have tried deriving a control from GridView and overriding the PointerWheelChanged event, but it never enters that event, as I think the internal scroll viewer is taking over. I tried to derive from ScrollViewer, but it is sealed and can't be done.

I am using a ItemsWrapGrid in the ItemsPanelTemplate, so perhaps there is something within that they I could override...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this post as an example, I was able to solve this:

[Pivot inside a ScrollViewer, scrollviewer wont scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429965/pivot-inside-a-scrollviewer-scrollviewer-wont-scroll)

Using the VisualTreeExtensions, I had to find and apply this method to a Grid that contained a ScrollContentPresenter. I did this in the OnLoaded event for my grid view.

```
private void gridView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var gridView = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, 0) as FrameworkElement;
        var grids = gridView.GetDescendantsOfType<Grid>().ToList();
        var oneIWant = grids.Where(x => x.Children.Any(y => y.GetType() == typeof(ScrollContentPresenter))).First();

        oneIWant.PointerWheelChanged += ScrollViewer_PointerWheelChanged;
    }
```

Not elegant, but it will make due for now. I am open to any other options that may be out there.

Comment: Doesnt this help  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"?

Comment: I needed to allow horizontal swiping to work on touch screens. Setting that to disabled prevented that from happening.