# UWP how to organize a gigantic input form

Tags: forms, uwp, pivot, flipview

I am working on an input form with 218 input controls divided over 20 sections.
What I did is to create a ViewModel for each section and define with a DataTemplate how it is supposed to look.
The main page for the form is a grid of tiles. A tile per section.
A section is a page in a FlipView where you can flip from one section to the next. A click on one of the tiles jumps directly to a page in the FlipView. Some sections contain a Pivot control that allow the creation of multiple items (i.E. persons). If the content in the Pivot is long, it needs a ScrollViewer. Pivots and ScrollViewer don't go well together. Scrolling does not work.
There is a SO question and answer that adresses this: [Pivot inside a ScrollViewer, scrollviewer wont scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429965/pivot-inside-a-scrollviewer-scrollviewer-wont-scroll)

The UWP Style Guide says

> Rather than overwhelm the screen with numerous input controls,
>   consider creating multiple pages for your form.

But it does not say how the pages should be organized.

So given a gigantic input form with 218 input controls and 20 sections where some of them can add multiple items, is there a better way to organize the form than what I attempt to do (FlipView, ViewModels, DataTemplates, Pivot, ScrollViewer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sections don't need to be filled out in a specific order, I suggest that you use the [NaviationView class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) and group each section as a Page.  The end result could be similar to the Settings app which has a number of disparate sections.

If the forms need to be filled out in a specific order, use the Frame/Page navigation and provide previous/next buttons on pages.

Comment: The form does not have to be filled out in a specific order. But since it is so large and jumping to different sections is allowed, I want to give an overview of what is already filled out by giving the tiles (or whatever else helps in navigation) a different background color when that section is valid (at least all required fields are filled out correctly). I already started looking into the NavigationView as a replacement for the Pivot inside of the individual sections. I will continue to experiment with it. Thank you.

Comment: There is quite a bit of code behind in the samples of NavigationView. I can't use it from a ResourceDictionary from DataTemplates. The way it is implemented at the moment, it is not MVVM friendly. I have to reorganize a lot to be able to use it.

Comment: UI design and code structure are different - you shouldn't let code structure an architecture define what UI paradigms and models that you use.  Think about how you want the UI to work and then figure out the right coding model to support that design.  Based on your question, the right UI model is the NavigationView - now as a developer, you are to determine how to implement it in the most efficient way possible.  When you've already committed code towards a different UI design, you are hesitant to change when you need to .  Get over that.